# Math.Net Numerics DelimitedReader.Read Format Exception

Tags: c#, csv, formatexception, mathnet-numerics

I am porting my MATLAB application to C# and decided to use Math.NET Numerics for it, but I am encountering the following problem: When I try to use delimited reader to load my csv into `Matrix<double> data`,

```
data = DelimitedReader.Read<double>(ofile.FileName, false, ",", true);
```

I am getting format exception; `ofile.FileName` is correct and my csv looks like this:

[image]

I searched for reasons, but didn't find the solution. Hopefully you will be able to help me, thank you in advance.

Kind regards.

EDIT1: providing csv as requested in comments [unixdates.csv](https://pastebin.com/92VXJwy1)

Comment: Please provide `unixdates.csv`.

Comment: @fuglede i edited post and provided pastebin with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When c# tries to parse a float, it uses the decimal separator of the current system language.
You're probably running under a language that uses a comma as the decimal separator, instead of the dot.

You can specify which format to use, though.

```
data = DelimitedReader.Read<double>(ofile.FileName, false, ",", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```